# Trouble understanding "recursion depth limit" in Python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I am wondering if someone can tell me if I understand this correctly.  I am writing a recursive function in Python (3.6) that will walk through an XML tree, processing each tag based on what kind of tag it is.  Some of these tags will actually indicate more complex elements as children which then need to be subsequently processed.

I have been reading about recursion in Python, and I'm aware that it's not necessarily the best language for it, but I still think that it will work for my purposes, as long as I understand what exactly the "recursion depth limit" is.

Given the following XML structure:

```
<a>
    ...
    <b>
        ...
        <c>
            ...
            <d>
                ...
                <e>
                    ...
                    <f>
                        ...
                    </f>
                </e>
            </d>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

And assuming that there will be a recursive call at every tag, then this would have a recursion depth of 6, correct?

Consequently, the following XML structure should only have a recursion depth of 2, it's just that the 2nd level will be called 6 times:

```
<a>
    ...
    <b>...</b>
    <b>...</b>
    <b>...</b>
    <b>...</b>
    <b>...</b>
    <b>...</b>
</a>
```

If I understand this correctly, I will only be going about 10 levels deep maximum, so I should not have to worry about it, but it is possible that some of these levels will be executed thousands (possibly even 10s of thousands) of times in sequence.  Other than just taking a really long time, are there any other memory-related considerations that should be taken into account?

The code I am using in the actual project is more detailed (each call to the function also gets a set of "rules" and other processing parameters encoded into dictionaries depending on the tag's name), but it goes similar to this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

rules_master = {
    "a": ... rules for processing 'a' element,
    "b": ... rules for processing 'b' element,
    ...
}

def import_feature(xml_element, rules):

    feature_type = xml_element.tag
    ... do more processing based on the rules parameter

    for child_element in list(xml_element):

        child_rules = rules_master[child_element.tag]
        import_feature(child_element, child_rules)

xml = ET.parse("path/to/xml/file")
top_level_element = xml.find("a")
import_feature(a, rules_master["a"]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "some of these levels will be executed thousands (possibly even 10s of thousands) of times in sequence."? Do you mean there could be many `b`s, but only under a single parent?

Comment: Yes, there could be thousands or tens of thousands of `b`s, but probably less than 10 `a`s.

Comment: ...But I should add that the tree will almost certainly not grow exponentially as one walks down its levels, for instance level `b` may have tens of thousands of entries, but level `c` can only ever have one entry per parent, and level `d` will not grow any larger than 50 or so.  The order of magnitude of the number of children at each step will be predictable and not exponential.

Comment: This depends on how it's implemented. Can you show some examples code?

Comment: I added a stripped down version of my code (original is far too specific)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You understand it perfectly. Recursion depth will not be an issue if the XML only nests ten elements deep.

> Other than just taking a really long time, are there any other memory-related considerations that should be taken into account?

There are essentially two main approaches to parsing XML: load it all into memory, or stream it and parse it as the file is read. Loading the entire document into memory makes processing it extremely easy. You can look up all elements by name, you can do XPath queries, etc. The tradeoffs are memory usage proportional to document size and not being able to do any processing until the entire document is read.

Streaming keeps memory usage constant, but you can't query arbitrary parts of the document at will. You have to process elements as you see them. If you want more than sequential access you have to jump through some hoops (like building up data structures as the document is processed). Sometimes streaming is the only approach: for example, if you have XML data being streamed to you and you need to process it as it comes in without waiting for the end.